# Why does $\partial A = \{ f({x_1},{x_2}):\left| {{x_i}} \right| \le 1,$ for each $i$ and equality holds for at least on $i\}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ is continuous map and $x,y\in \mathbb{C}$ and $A = \{ f({x_1},{x_2}):\left| {{x_i}} \right| \le 1,i = 1,2\} $

Can we say that

$\partial A = \{ f({x_1},{x_2}):\left| {{x_i}} \right| \le 1,$ for each $i$ and equality holds for at least on $i\}$?

($\partial A$ is boundary of $A$)

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily. For example, let $f$ be the map that glues the entire boundary together. In this case you would get a four-sphere, which has no boundary.

If you mean boundary in the sense of topology, the question is not well-defined. You need to have two spaces to define boundary: a big space and a subset of the space. Only then can you talk of the boundary of the subset in the larger space.

I'll give you two examples. Let $f$ be the map that sends all of the square to a point as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If we give $\mathbb{R}$ the usual (Euclidean) topology, it is clear that the point is closed, but not open. Therefore, the point is a boundary. Now consider the map which sends all of the square to a point in $\mathbb{R}$, but give $\mathbb{R}$ the trivial topology. In this case all of $\mathbb{R}$ is the boundary of your point.

Comment: I don't understand Please more guide.

Comment: Could you tell me your definition of boundary?

Comment: $\partial A = \bar A - A^\circ$

Comment: In that case, it is not well-defined. You need to have two spaces to define boundary: a big space and a subset of the space. Only then can you talk of the boundary of the subset in the larger space.

Comment: Why $\partial A = \{ f({x_1},{x_2}):\left| {{x_i}} \right| = 1,$ for each $i$ $\}$ is true?

Comment: I edited my answer. I think this explains why your question is not well-defined.